# Why Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<...>!=null) does not work?

Tags: .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, code-contracts

Why do I got warning "CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'stream'." on this code sample?

```
public static void Test()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("some url");
    Contract.Assume(request != null);
    var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Flush(); // WARNING IN THIS LINE
}
```

I am asking because I use Reflector at System.Contracts.dll and there is next line in GetRequestStream() method of HttpWebRequest class:

```
public virtual Stream GetRequestStream()
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Stream>() != null, null, "Contract.Result<System.IO.Stream>() != null");
}
```

Comment: I can replicate this, and it looks like a bug. You could try asking on  the Code Contracts forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/codecontracts/threads

Answer (score 1):

That contract is ignored because there is no method to which it applies. There is no `public virtual Stream GetRequestStream` in `HttpWebRequest`. There is, however, a `public virtual Stream GetRequestStream` in `WebRequest`, and there is a `public override Stream GetRequestStream` in `HttpWebRequest`, but neither of those have any contracts in `System.Contracts.dll`.

You can report it as a bug, and you can use `Contract.Assume` to avoid the warning.